# execute script from another script not working

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables

I am using shell scripts to compile the different components. I have one main script which is calling another shell script.
Here is an example,

```shell
Repo/build.sh
Repo/code/mode/1/build/build_1.sh
```

Now if I go to `Repo/code/mode/1/build/` folder and run the script `build_1.sh` then it is working.

But if call the script `build_1.sh` from `build.sh` then build doesn't work.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
REPO=/home/${USER}/project
set -o errexit
set -o nounset
set -o pipefail

(cd ${REPO}/code/mode/1/build/; ./build_1.sh)
```

What could be the reason that above approach is not working. Consider `REPO` env is already set.

Comment: How? Please add that to your question. Show us how you set it, and how you launch the script. The details are important. If you just do `REPO=/path` and then run your script, the variable won't be defined. So, please [edit] and add the exact commands you use to set the variable's value and to launch the script.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Show them. (you can [edit] your question) If that doesn't tell anything, run the script with `set -x` (i.e. add that to start, or run it with `bash -x build.sh` or so.) and see what it says it actually runs?

Comment: Updated the script.

Comment: OK, so how does this "not work"? Do you get an error message? If you define the variable in the script, that should work unless the path is wrong so the `cd` fails or there is no `./build.sh` in the target directory, or that script isn't executable. All of these should give you a different error message. What do you see?

Comment: You have 2 shebang lines at the top of your script - which one do you hope is actually being executed?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that while you set the `REPO` *shell variable*, you don't `export`  it to make it an *environment variable*.

Unfortunately, you haven't provided details on *how* the build doesn't work if `build_1.sh` is called from within `build.sh`, but if your subordinate script depends on the `REPO` variable, then it will run into problems because
unless you export it, a subordinate script will not see it.

The remedy is *probably*  (as I said, the question is still lacking some details) to actually export the variable. For that, simply state

```bash
export REPO=/home/${USER}/project
```

in your script.

Thanks to @ilkkachu for pointing out a fundamental error in my reasoning for a previous version of this answer.